# Android: Issue in storing and retrieving files from Directory in android 4.0 and above

Tags: android

I am writing this following code to get the public directory from my android device. And the issue that is arising , is while i use this code to run on gingerbread version, its running fine. But when i am using the same code on Android 4.0 version and above, I am getting a null pointer exception while retrieving the files from the same directory.

```
    public  File getDir() {
    File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    Log.d("MyMSg", "Directory Returned"+sdDir);
    return new File(sdDir, "MyPictures");


      }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In which line does it give the NPE?

Comment: @Henry on Line number 4 in the above code i.e. while returning the directory. Actually what i have observed is while using this code for saving purpose, it works fine for android 4.0 and above but while retrieving from the same directory, using same code to get the directory its throwing NPE .

Comment: This can only happen when `sdDir` is `null`. You should see that in logcat from the log statement above. Regarding your second remark, the method doesn't know if you want to read or write, so this should not make a difference.

Comment: @Henry in gingerbread version there is only one sdcard options whereas in in ICS and above there is option of two sdcard, they are
 1>sd card